# Filtrar galeria Wordpress de acordo com o click no Post

Tags: php, wordpress, filtro, carousel

Fala galera, tenho um carousel onde publico algumas fotos através de post no wordpress e preciso que ao clicar no titulo do post no sidebar, a galeria correspondente apareça, alguém me sugere como posso fazer? desde ja agradeço!

SIDEBAR

```
        if(have_posts()) {
            while(have_posts()){
                the_post(); 
        ?>

        <a href="#!"><p class="text-salvador"><?php the_title(); ?> </p></a>

        <?php }
        }else{
            // resultado caso não tenha nada publicado
        Echo "<p style='color:white;' class='text-center'>Oops<br> não foi publicado nada ainda ainda</p>";
        }
        // Encerramento da query
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

LOOP DA GALERIA

> ```
>                 if(have_posts()) {
>                     while(have_posts()){
>                         the_post(); 
>                 ?>
>                 <?php $images = get_field('galeria_the_hostel_rio_de_janeiro');
>                     $size = 'full';
>                         if( $images ): ?>
>                 <?php 
>
>                     $n = 1;
>
>                      foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
>                     <?php 
>
>                         if ( $n == 1) {
>                             echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
>                                     <img class="d-block w-100" src="'.$image["url"].'" alt="First slide">
>                                 </div>';
>                         }else{
>                             echo '<div class="carousel-item">
>                                     <img class="d-block w-100" src="'.$image["url"].'" alt="First slide">
>                                 </div>';
>                         } $n++;
>
>                     ?>
>
>                 <?php endforeach; ?>
>                 <?php endif; ?>
> ```

GALERIA VIEW

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer levar para o post correspondente da imagem é isso?

Comment: Então, eu tenho um carousel unico na lateral direita e terei uma lista com os posts na lateral esquerda, quando houver o click no post preciso chamar as imagens dele para esta unica galeria, seria uma especie de filtro

Comment: Mas como você vinculou as fotos ao post? tem bastante formas

Comment: Criei a galeria utlizando o Plugin Advanced Custom Field, e vinculei ela ao meu post

Comment: Tá então é fácil, mas você tem 2 formas de fazer, você quer que a página atualize? ou não? Caso não queria será preciso utilizar ajax

Comment: Eu prefiria utilizar via ajax pra ficar com um efeito legal